# How to access packer machine (IP/host) through ansible during build

Tags: ansible, packer

I am trying to build my application using packer and ansible integration provisioner  using GCP . But in the build process I need to execute some curl commands and I am not able to find how to do the same.

I have already tried "localhost"  and then some ansible variables like "{{ ansible_host }}" (returning 127.0.0.1 which does not work)  and "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}" (Variable not found)

I am using these in a yml.j2 file. Can that be the reason for the issue.

error -->
test with "ansible_host"

```
[0;32m    googlecompute: TASK [deploy-XXXXX : Create the XXXXX collection] ***************************[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "content": "", "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8765/api/v1/collections/XXXXX"}[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute:    to retry, use: --limit @/deploy-XXXXX.retry[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute:[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute: localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1[0m
```

test with "ansible_default_ipv4.address"

```
[0;32m    googlecompute: TASK [deploy-XXXXX : copy environment specific variables] *********************[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible_default_ipv4' is undefined"}[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute:    to retry, use: --limit @/deploy-XXXXX.retry[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute:[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute: localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1[0m
[0;32m    googlecompute:[0m
```

Here the playbook snippet

```
- name: Validate server runing
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:{{ port }}/validate"
    method: PUT
    body_format: json
    body: "{\"test\":\"validate\"}"
    status_code: 200
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
```

Comment: Provide the part of the playbook you have problem with and explain what you need to do.

Comment: Updated snippet from playbook

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this problem by adding delegate_to: default to task. e.g.

```
- name: Validate server runing
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:{{ port }}/validate"
    method: PUT
    body_format: json
    body: "{\"test\":\"validate\"}"
    status_code: 200
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
  delegate_to: default
```